# Next.js: middlewares without a custom server or wrappers

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Is it possible to create a Next.js app with middlewares without using a custom server nor wrappers handlers?

When I create an Express app, I split my code into different require statements calling Express middlewares:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// I call the functions in each modules to use the different middlewares
require("./startup/cors")(app);
require("./startup/routes")(app);
require("./startup/db")();

const port = process.env.PORT || config.get("port");
const server = app.listen(port, () =>
  winston.info(`Listening on port ${port}...`)
);

module.exports = server;
```

For example, the `./startup/cors` module contains the following lines:

```
const cors = require("cors");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(cors());
};
```

However, with my Next.js app, I don't understand how to get something like this without creating a custom server.

I already came across the article [Use middleware in Next.js without custom server](https://hoangvvo.com/blog/middlewares-in-next-js-without-custom-server/) but it uses a wrapper solution I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Next.js supports [middlewares](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares) only for api paths. There is no support for middlewares in regular pages paths yet.